# Best Practices for Video Uploads to Wordpress

Tags: videos

I'm working on a theme and one of the features I'm quite happy with is the slider supports background videos. The problem is however, that Wordpress (although I think it's more a PHP issue) has a limit of 2MB on file uploads, and as you know, most videos are bigger than that.

So I haven't got that much experience with themes, but what is the best practice in this situation? I guess users could use youtube and link to those videos, but that seems a bit drawn out.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: You can increase the maximum upload size, depending on your server config, there are a number of different things that will work.  Google "Increase WordPress max upload size".

Answer (score 0):

In general, streaming video directly from your site isn't advised. You can increase Max Upload size by making edits in php.ini or .htaccess, but your visitors may experience significant buffering, or even worse, extended page load times.  You should consider having the videos stream from S3 or one of the hosted services.

Comment: I know that's true, but I'm selling this theme to users and want to make it as easy as possible.

Comment: It's definitely a function of their hosting environment. You may want to provide minimum technical requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is bit old.

Upload limit based on Server configuration how the account has been set up. Sometime it is 2MB, sometime 8MB or more.

It depends on WordPress Media upload size which is visible in media library. Write "how to  increase the upload limit" FAQ in you theme requirement file like other theme or plugin author dos because it is a known issue.

Check this reference, you can add all this in the theme FAQ, "[how to increase limit](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/)"

Thanks